# Send 'selections created by vscode expand/shrink' to neovim

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

vscode-neovim plugin didn't work well with expand/shrink.

We can select code blocks using vscode's expand/shrink action.

When using vscode-neovim plugin,cause the editor's expand/shrink actions are triggered directly by vscode (without neovim visual mode on). So when selection done, neovim will unable to handle these selections right.

Is there a way configure the plugin to work with these selections?